# Initializer being called before gem in Ruby 2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails 3.2 app running on Ruby 1.9.3, and I was asked to update it to Ruby 2.1 and, later, Rails 4.1. I'm having a problem upgrading to Ruby 2.1 though:

Our company have a gem that's used by our systems and defines some global constants. The application has to overwrite these constants in development (we know it's hacky, but it's temporary until we can get our staging server back on), so I have an `Initializer` file that overwrites these constants. That worked fine so far, I get some warnings on the server console (`warning: already initialized constant ...`) but it worked.

Now, however, Rails seems to be calling my custom initializer before the gem, does anyone know of a change in Ruby 2.0 or 2.1 that may induce this change of behaviour? Note that I'm still using Rails 3.2, I just updated a few gems to make it compatible with the new Ruby.

This is how I set the constant in the initializer and gem (both files have the same name and are basically the same). The constant that needs to be overwritten is URL_PORTAL:

```
module Portal
  module Sso

    URL_PORTAL_PRODUCTION = "(URL1)"
    URL_PORTAL_DEVELOPMENT = "(URL2)" # I overwrite this in the initializer
    URL_PORTAL_TEST = "(URL3)"

    URL_PORTAL = case Rails.env
      when "production" then URL_PORTAL_PRODUCTION
      when "test" then URL_PORTAL_TEST
      else URL_PORTAL_DEVELOPMENT
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: As a note, constants are annoying because they're hard to override. It's much better to implement these as methods that return constant values, as those are easy to redo. For example, use `matt_accessor`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `require 'portal/seo'` (or other appropriate filename) in the begining of the file.